# Ошибка "Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle"

Tags: java, android

Вот лог ошибки:

```
 07-01 21:51:49.823 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.823 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 274 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.823 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x00f1
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 575: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0101
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onVisibleBehindCanceled, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 188: Landroid/app/Activity;.onVisibleBehindCanceled ()V
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0111
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 192: Landroid/app/Activity;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0137
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 274 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x019a
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.824 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 225 (Landroid/media/session/MediaController;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.825 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01b2
07-01 21:51:49.825 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.825 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2044 (Landroid/widget/Toolbar;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.825 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01bc
07-01 21:51:49.825 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onStateNotSaved, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.825 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 180: Landroid/app/Activity;.onStateNotSaved ()V
07-01 21:51:49.825 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x01c4
07-01 21:51:49.826 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.releaseInstance, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.826 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 199: Landroid/app/Activity;.releaseInstance ()Z
07-01 21:51:49.826 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x02bf
07-01 21:51:49.826 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onActivityReenter, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.826 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 115: Landroid/app/Activity;.onActivityReenter (ILandroid/content/Intent;)V
07-01 21:51:49.826 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x02d6
07-01 21:51:49.826 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.826 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 652: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
07-01 21:51:49.826 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x032b
07-01 21:51:49.827 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getVoiceInteractor, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.827 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 94: Landroid/app/Activity;.getVoiceInteractor ()Landroid/app/VoiceInteractor;
07-01 21:51:49.827 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x044c
07-01 21:51:49.827 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.827 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 25 (Landroid/app/ActivityManager$TaskDescription;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.828 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x050d
07-01 21:51:49.828 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.startActionMode, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.828 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 243: Landroid/app/Activity;.startActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
07-01 21:51:49.828 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0548
07-01 21:51:49.828 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.showAssist, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.828 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 238: Landroid/app/Activity;.showAssist (Landroid/os/Bundle;)Z
07-01 21:51:49.828 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x058a
07-01 21:51:49.828 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.postponeEnterTransition, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.828 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 196: Landroid/app/Activity;.postponeEnterTransition ()V
07-01 21:51:49.828 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0595
07-01 21:51:49.829 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.829 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 664: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
07-01 21:51:49.829 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x05fc
07-01 21:51:49.829 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.829 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 202: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestPermissions ([Ljava/lang/String;I)V
07-01 21:51:49.829 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x06ee
07-01 21:51:49.830 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.830 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 63 (Landroid/app/SharedElementCallback;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.830 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0708
07-01 21:51:49.830 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.830 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 274 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.830 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x074f
07-01 21:51:49.830 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDirs, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.830 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 659: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getExternalFilesDirs (Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/io/File;
07-01 21:51:49.830 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x07df
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.TransitionManager', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1851 (Landroid/transition/TransitionManager;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0895
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onProvideReferrer, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 168: Landroid/app/Activity;.onProvideReferrer ()Landroid/net/Uri;
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x08c7
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 579: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0920
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.showLockTaskEscapeMessage, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 241: Landroid/app/Activity;.showLockTaskEscapeMessage ()V
07-01 21:51:49.831 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0930
07-01 21:51:49.832 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getContentTransitionManager, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.832 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 67: Landroid/app/Activity;.getContentTransitionManager ()Landroid/transition/TransitionManager;
07-01 21:51:49.832 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0936
07-01 21:51:49.832 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.832 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 63 (Landroid/app/SharedElementCallback;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.832 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x09f2
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getReferrer, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 82: Landroid/app/Activity;.getReferrer ()Landroid/net/Uri;
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0a4e
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemServiceName, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 673: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getSystemServiceName (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0ac5
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.isVoiceInteractionRoot, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 107: Landroid/app/Activity;.isVoiceInteractionRoot ()Z
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0ae7
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalMediaDirs, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 660: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getExternalMediaDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0b69
07-01 21:51:49.833 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getMediaController, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 75: Landroid/app/Activity;.getMediaController ()Landroid/media/session/MediaController;
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0bad
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getSearchEvent, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 85: Landroid/app/Activity;.getSearchEvent ()Landroid/view/SearchEvent;
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0c13
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onRequestPermissionsResult, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 169: Landroid/app/Activity;.onRequestPermissionsResult (I[Ljava/lang/String;[I)V
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0c39
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.isVoiceInteraction, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 106: Landroid/app/Activity;.isVoiceInteraction ()Z
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0cb7
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestVisibleBehind, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 203: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestVisibleBehind (Z)Z
07-01 21:51:49.834 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d12
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 236: Landroid/app/Activity;.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d27
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onProvideAssistData, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 167: Landroid/app/Activity;.onProvideAssistData (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d3c
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.finishAndRemoveTask, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 57: Landroid/app/Activity;.finishAndRemoveTask ()V
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d56
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 574: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d8a
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.reportFullyDrawn, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 201: Landroid/app/Activity;.reportFullyDrawn ()V
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0db8
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 67 (Landroid/app/assist/AssistContent;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.835 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0de2
07-01 21:51:49.836 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.finishAfterTransition, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.836 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 56: Landroid/app/Activity;.finishAfterTransition ()V
07-01 21:51:49.836 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0e06
07-01 21:51:49.836 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getContentScene, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.836 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 66: Landroid/app/Activity;.getContentScene ()Landroid/transition/Scene;
07-01 21:51:49.836 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0e0c
07-01 21:51:49.837 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.837 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1897 (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.837 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0f3b
07-01 21:51:49.837 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.startLockTask, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.837 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 262: Landroid/app/Activity;.startLockTask ()V
07-01 21:51:49.837 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x101b
07-01 21:51:49.837 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.837 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 628: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
07-01 21:51:49.837 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x108e
07-01 21:51:49.838 20146-20146/giftapp.gift E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.838 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 274 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lgiftapp/gift/LoginActivity;
07-01 21:51:49.838 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x1192
07-01 21:51:49.839 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getObbDirs, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.839 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 666: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getObbDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
07-01 21:51:49.839 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x11b9
07-01 21:51:49.839 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.startPostponedEnterTransition, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.839 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 266: Landroid/app/Activity;.startPostponedEnterTransition ()V
07-01 21:51:49.839 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x11bf
07-01 21:51:49.839 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalCacheDirs, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.839 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 657: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getExternalCacheDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
07-01 21:51:49.839 20146-20146/giftapp.gift D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x122b
07-01 21:51:49.839 20146-20146/giftapp.gift I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onEnterAnimationComplete, referenced from method giftapp.gift.LoginActivity.access$super
07-01 21:51:49.839 20146-20146/giftapp.gift W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 141: Landroid/app/Activity;.onEnterAnimationComplete ()V
```

Программа не крашится, но все кнопки в активности перестают работать.
Прикрепляю build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "giftapp.gift"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-facebook:0.3.3.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-googleplus:0.3.3.3'
}
```

Comment: А у вас в активити вот такого метода, часом, нема: `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)`?

Comment: Узнали ответ на вопрос? Можно увидеть решение?